# How to pickle a class instance if the class has another instance of different class?

Tags: python, pickle, dill, chatterbot

So I am trying to build a chatbot using the famous "chatterbot" library in python. I made a class called Trainer which trains my chatbot. So in this class I am initializing the instance for the class "chatterbot" and then training it. So, to avoid retraining it again and again I though to pickle the instance of my Trainer class. So if it already exist, I don't need to retrain it and hence I am trying to pickle the Trainer class instance. I am using dill library to pickle the class instance but as it tries to pickle my model, it shows me the following error:

> > _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle >'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>: it's not the same object as >>sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session

Now, I don't see anywhere in my code that I have created any kind of session. But I believe the *chatterbot* library that I am using in my Trainer class must be using any kind of session in it. Infact I checked the source code and it is using the logger. So it might be possible that's causing the pain. I have no clue how to proceed with this problem. I tried to change the source code of *chatterbot* library and removed every occurrence of logger from it but I did nothing but broke the code. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue. I am attaching required code here.

**utils**:

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import pickle
import dill
import  os
from .trainer import Trainer

# Method returns the directories in which model objects are stored/saved.
def model_base_dir():
    directory = 'MLModel/pickled_models'
    parent_directory = os.pardir
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(parent_directory,directory))

def picked_model(base_dir=None):
    if base_dir == None:
        logging.exception("Base Directory does not exist !!!")
        raise AssertionError("Base Directory does not exist !!!")

    model_path = base_dir+'/version1.pickle'
    if Path(model_path).is_file():
        with open(model_path,'rb') as handle:
            model = dill.load(handle)
        return model
    else:
        return None


def save_model(model_obj):
    dir = model_base_dir()    # Get the directory where model needs to be saved
    with open(dir+'/version1.pickle','wb') as f:
        dill.dump(model_obj,f)
        f.close()


def train_model():
    mod_obj = Trainer()
    save_model(mod_obj)
    return mod_obj
```

**Trainer**

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

class Trainer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.chatbot = ChatBot('Dexter')
        self.create_chatbot_trainer(language="chatterbot.corpus.english")

    def train_chatbot(self,trainer,language):
        return trainer.train(language)

    def create_chatbot_trainer(self,language):
        self.trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(self.chatbot)
        self.trainer = self.train_chatbot(self.trainer,language)
        return self.trainer

    def __getstate__(self):
        d = self.__dict__.copy()
        d.pop('_parents',None)
        return d

    def response(self,text=""):
        if text is None:
            return "Sorry, your query is empty"
        else:
            return self.chatbot.get_response(text)
```

The train_model() gets trigger from my django view.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You might want to try some of the other `dill.settings`, which provide different serialization variants.  You can modify the settings globally, or within a single instance of a `dump`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I guess there are quite a few settings possible and which combination of setting will suit would be hard to tell. If you can direct little more, that would be a lot help. I tried dumps and loads. Doesn't work.

Comment: `dill.settings`:  `ignore=True` disables halt on serialization dependency failure, `recurse=False` disables recursive pickling for globals, `byref=False` disables pickling by reference.  I'm not sure what combinations will work, if any.  It looks like something in `chatterbot` has some unserializable dependency on something in `sqlalchemy`